# Create BAT file to get directory listing up to 2nd level only

Tags: batch-file, directory-structure

I have a window directory with 300 folders inside of it and 4 levels of folders within each folder. I  need a listing of folders only up to 2nd level in a txt file? I need the full path of each directory as well. I would like to use this a BAT file or CMD line prompt. Ex:

```
Jon Done
Test001
Tester002
Test003
Tester004
```

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d 2^>nul') DO ECHO %%~fa
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /ad') DO (
 PUSHD "%%a"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN ('dir /b /a-d 2^>nul') DO ECHO %%~fx
 popd
)

popd

GOTO :EOF
```

This should work - you would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.